# Can't drag image to design tab in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't drag image in design tab in android studio i got this not allowed mark any help
pic of my android studio

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just drag and drop png image in your layout. Firstly you need add ImageView widget, then specify src parameter like this `android:src="@drawable/cat1"`.

Answer (score 0):

You only can add image into `mipmap` folder, not in `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Android Studio we can do that easily by Resource Manager , just by selecting Resource manager from left side and drag and drop image to Design tab.

[Left side of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbyk4.png)

[Its Appear like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ba2.png)

We can check out the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/resource-manager) for details usage of resource manager.